# Обновление DataGridView не работает из события кнопки Click

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите, почему так происходит и как сделать правильно.

Такой код работает:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public List<Student> data = new List<Student>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = data;

        data.Add(new Student() {
            name = "Василий",
            fam = "Бережнов"
        });
        data.Add(new Student() {
            name = "Петр",
            fam = "Бережнов"
        });

    }
}
```

А такой нет

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public List<Student> data = new List<Student>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        data.Add(new Student() {
            name = "Василий",
            fam = "Бережнов"
        });
    }
}
```

Всякие Update и Refersh не помогают, хотя записи в data идут.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В качестве источника данных DataSource в WinForms желательно устанавливать BindingList<T>, при добавлении записей в него dataGridView будет обновляться, и при изменении данных в гриде будет обновлять содержимое BindingList.

Answer (score 0):

Каждый раз при обновлении списка data надо делать ручную привязку:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
```

т.е. в данном случае кинуть эту строчку в обработчик события кнопки. Но, как уже ответили, лучше список объявить как `BindingList<T>`:

```
public BindingList<Student> data = new BindingList<Student>();
```